# How to use Spark SQL DataFrame with flatMap?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the Spark Scala API. I have a Spark SQL DataFrame (read from an Avro file) with the following schema:

```
root
|-- ids: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- key: integer
|    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
|-- match: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Essentially 2 columns [ ids: List[Map[Int, String]], match: List[Int] ]. Sample data that looks like:

```
[List(Map(1 -> a), Map(2 -> b), Map(3 -> c), Map(4 -> d)),List(0, 0, 1, 0)]
[List(Map(5 -> c), Map(6 -> a), Map(7 -> e), Map(8 -> d)),List(1, 0, 1, 0)]
...
```

What I would like to do is `flatMap()` each row to produce 3 columns [**id**, **property**, **match**]. Using the above 2 rows as the input data we would get:

```
[1,a,0]
[2,b,0]
[3,c,1]
[4,d,0]
[5,c,1]
[6,a,0]
[7,e,1]
[8,d,0]
...
```

and then `groupBy` the `String` **property** (ex: a, b, ...) to produce `count("property")` and `sum("match")`:

```
 a    2    0
 b    1    0
 c    2    2
 d    2    0
 e    1    1
```

I would want to do something like:

```
val result = myDataFrame.select("ids","match").flatMap( 
    (row: Row) => row.getList[Map[Int,String]](1).toArray() )
result.groupBy("property").agg(Map(
    "property" -> "count",
    "match" -> "sum" ) )
```

The problem is that the `flatMap` converts DataFrame to RDD. Is there a good way to do a `flatMap` type operation followed by `groupBy` using DataFrames?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What does `flatMap` do that you want? It converts each input row into 0 or more rows. It can filter them out, or it can add new ones. In SQL to get the same functionality you use `join`. Can you do what you want to do with a `join`?

Alternatively, you could also look at `Dataframe.explode`, which is just a specific kind of `join` (you can easily craft your own `explode` by joining a DataFrame to a UDF). `explode` takes a single column as input and lets you split it or convert it into multiple values and then `join` the original row back onto the new rows. So:

```
user      groups
griffin   mkt,it,admin
```

Could become:

```
user      group
griffin   mkt
griffin   it
griffin   admin
```

So I would say take a look at `DataFrame.explode` and if that doesn't get you there easily, try joins with UDFs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The DataFrame.explode method is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My SQL is a bit rusty, but one option is in your flatMap to produce a list of Row objects and then you can convert the resulting RDD back into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
`myDataFrame.select(explode('ids as "ids",'match).
select( 'ids, explode('match as "match").
map ( r => {
val e=r.getMap[Int,String](0).head
(e._1,e._2,r.getInt(1))
}
)`
```

groupby ..... can be run after

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).