# How can I disaggregate rows of a data frame in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe containing data similar to the following:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| ID |      Timestamp      | Value | Interval | Consumption |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | 2012-05-02 12:30:00 |   550 |        1 |           5 |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 12:45:00 |   551 |        1 |           1 |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:00:00 |   554 |        1 |           3 |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:00:00 |   578 |        4 |          24 |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:15:00 |   578 |        1 |           0 |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:30:00 |   584 |        1 |           6 |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

I'm looking to turn this into something like the following:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
| ID |      Timestamp      | Value | Interval | Consumption | Estimation |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | 2012-05-02 12:30:00 |   550 |        1 |           5 | ?          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 12:45:00 |   551 |        1 |           1 | ?          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:00:00 |   554 |        1 |           3 | ?          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:15:00 |   560 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:30:00 |   566 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:45:00 |   572 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:00:00 |   578 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:15:00 |   578 |        1 |           0 | ?          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:30:00 |   584 |        1 |           6 | ?          |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

More specifically I want to turn this:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| ID |      Timestamp      | Value | Interval | Consumption |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:00:00 |   578 |        4 |          24 |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Into this:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
| ID |      Timestamp      | Value | Interval | Consumption | Estimation |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:15:00 |   560 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:30:00 |   566 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 13:45:00 |   572 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
|  1 | 2012-05-02 14:00:00 |   578 |        1 |           6 | 4          |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

I want to take the rows with more than 1 interval out of the original table, interpolate Values for missing intervals and reinsert the newly created rows into the initial table place of the original rows. I have ideas of how to achieve this (in PostgreSQL for example I would simply use the generate_series() function to create the required Timestamps and calculate new Values), but implementing these in Spark/Scala is proving troublesome.

Assuming I've created a new dataframe containing only rows with Interval > 1, how could I replicate those rows 'n' times with 'n' being the value of Interval? I believe that would give me enough to get going using a Counter function partitioned by some row reference I can create.

If there's a way to replicate the behavior of generate_series() that I've missed, even better.

Comment: Sounds like `flatMap` is the right tool for this job, see details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381359/how-to-use-spark-sql-dataframe-with-flatmap

Comment: Your suggestion is much appreciated, I'll take a look now. Thank you.

Comment: That's funny -- I forgot I had answered the other question. And, I had forgotten that I knew how to mimic an `explode` by using `join` and a `UDF` on the right side of the `join` !! (Remember to upvote my answer! :-)

Comment: David, I've been reading the documentation and searching for examples. It seems that most applications of `flatMap`, `df.explode()` and `LATERAL VIEW` have a `map` or `UDF` with a fixed number of outputs. In my case I'd like to turn the value `n` of 'Interval' into an array or list from `1 to n` and join each element to the corresponding row, hence creating `n` copies of each row. Would this work? I'm struggling to see how to acheive this.