# Flatmap on dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, flatmap

What is the best way to preform a `flatMap` on a `DataFrame` in spark? 
From searching around and doing some testing, I have come up with two different approaches. Both of these have some drawbacks so I'm thinking that there should be some better/easier way to do it.

The first way I have found is to first convert the `DataFrame` into an `RDD` and then back again:

```
val map = Map("a" -> List("c","d","e"), "b" -> List("f","g","h"))
val df = List(("a", 1.0), ("b", 2.0)).toDF("x", "y")

val rdd = df.rdd.flatMap{ row =>
  val x = row.getAs[String]("x")
  val x = row.getAs[Double]("y")
  for(v <- map(x)) yield Row(v,y)
}
val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
```

The second approach is to create a `DataSet` before using the `flatMap` (using the same variables as above) and then convert back:

```
val ds = df.as[(String, Double)].flatMap{
  case (x, y) => for(v <- map(x)) yield (v,y)
}.toDF("x", "y")
```

Both these approaches work quite well when the number of columns are small, however I have a lot more than 2 columns. Is there any better way to solve this problem? Preferably in a way where no conversion is necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Spark SQL DataFrame with flatMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381359/how-to-use-spark-sql-dataframe-with-flatmap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a second `dataframe` from your `map` RDD:

```
val mapDF = Map("a" -> List("c","d","e"), "b" -> List("f","g","h")).toList.toDF("key", "value")
```

Then do the `join` and apply the `explode` function:

```
val joinedDF = df.join(mapDF, df("x") === mapDF("key"), "inner")
  .select("value", "y")
  .withColumn("value", explode($"value"))
```

And you get the solution.

```
joinedDF.show()
```