# exploding an spark data frame column which is in the form of array

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a spark dataframe :

```
Id   |   events
----------------
A    |  [{"itemIds":["1","21","3"],"eventtype":"sp"},{"eventtype":"hp"},{"itemIds":["5"],"eventtype":"ip"}]

B    |  [{"itemIds":["8","10"],"eventtype":"bp"},{"eventtype":"atc"}]
```

here both Id and events column are of string type .

How can i convert the above data frame to the data frame below (where ever "itemIds" is not present it is filled with a null value):

```
Id    |  itemIds  |   eventtype
---------------------------------

A     |     1     |     sp

A     |     21    |     sp

A     |     3     |     sp

A     |    null   |     hp

A     |     5     |     ip

B     |     8     |     bp

B     |     10    |     bp

B     |     null  |     atc
```

Here Id , itemIds , event type columns are of String type .

Comment: Have you looked for an API methods over Dataframe or even on similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396424/631176)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, In which parsed json using json4j and then exploded items.

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

case class Items(itemIds: Array[String], eventtype: String)
case class Item(id: String, itemId: String, etype: String)

val df = Seq(("A","""[{"itemIds":["1","21","3"],"eventtype":"sp"},{"eventtype":"hp"},{"itemIds":["5"],"eventtype":"ip"}]"""),("B","""[{"itemIds":["8","10"],"eventtype":"bp"},{"eventtype":"atc"}]""")).toDF("id","json")

df.flatMap(r => {
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse(r.getString(1)).extract[Array[Items]].flatMap(i => {
    if(i.itemIds.isEmpty)
      List(Item(r.getString(0), null, i.eventtype))
    else
      (0 until i.itemIds.size).map(j => Item(r.getString(0), i.itemIds(j), i.eventtype))
  })
})
```